# How do i slow down the reverse of a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I am using the following plugin:

http://unslider.com/

The file in question is unslider.js

When the last slide is over the script goes back to the first slide but it does it very fast.  I am new to JS so not sure how I can slow down the script when it's going back to the first slide.  So when displaying it it goes from 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 but then when reversing it goes fast from 4 - 3 - 2 - 1.  Any ideas?

These are the options I've been playing with but no luck:

```
    //  Set some options
    _.o = {
        speed: 800,   // animation speed, false for no transition (integer or boolean)
        delay: 5000,  // delay between slides, false for no autoplay (integer or boolean)
        init: 0,      // init delay, false for no delay (integer or boolean)
        pause: !f,    // pause on hover (boolean)
        loop: !f,     // infinitely looping (boolean)
        keys: true,      // keyboard shortcuts (boolean)
        dots: true,      // display ••••o• pagination (boolean)
        arrows: true,    // display prev/next arrows (boolean)
        prev: '',    // text or html inside prev button (string)
        next: '',    // same as for prev option
        fluid: true,     // is it a percentage width? (boolean)
        complete: f,  // invoke after animation (function with argument)
        items: '>ul', // slides container selector
        item: '>li'   // slidable items selector
    };
```

And I think this might be relevant but not sure what to do:

```
        //  To slide or not to slide
        if ((!target.length || index < 0) && o.loop == f) return;

        //  Check if it's out of bounds
        if (!target.length) index = 0;
        if (index < 0) index = li.length - 1;
        target = li.eq(index);

        var speed = callback ? 5 : o.speed | 0,
            obj = {height: target.outerHeight()};

        if (!ul.queue('fx').length) {
            //  Handle those pesky dots
            el.find('.dot').eq(index).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            el.animate(obj, speed) && ul.animate($.extend({left: '-' + index + '00%'}, obj), speed, function(data) {
                _.i = index;

                $.isFunction(o.complete) && !callback && o.complete(el);
            });
        };
    };
```

In the above line i tried playing with this one: var speed = callback ? 5 : o.speed | 0,

I tried adding different numbers in place of the 5 but it didn't do the trick.

Please advise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to set a new speed value only when it's out of bounds adding one boolean var and if it´s true then change speed value like this

```
    //  Check if it's out of bounds
    var reversespeed=false;//default to false
    if (!target.length){
        index = 0;
        reversespeed=true;//go to first li
    }
    if (index < 0){
        index = li.length - 1;
        reversespeed=true;//go to last li
    }
    target = li.eq(index);

    var speed = callback ? 5 : o.speed | 0,
        obj = {height: target.outerHeight()};
    if(reversespeed){
        speed=50000;//add new speed for reverse
    }
    if (!ul.queue('fx').length) {
        //  Handle those pesky dots
        el.find('.dot').eq(index).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        el.animate(obj, speed) && ul.animate($.extend({left: '-' + index + '00%'}, obj), speed, function(data) {
            _.i = index;

            $.isFunction(o.complete) && !callback && o.complete(el);
        });
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqRFK/
UPDATE
to go back immediately without it showing the previous slides change speed to 0 when it is out of bounds

```
  //  Check if it's out of bounds
    var reversespeed=false;//default to false
    if (!target.length){
        index = 0;
        reversespeed=true;//go to first li
    }
    if (index < 0){
        index = li.length - 1;
        reversespeed=true;//go to last li
    }
    target = li.eq(index);

    var speed = callback ? 5 : o.speed | 0,
        obj = {height: target.outerHeight()};
    if(reversespeed){
        speed=0;
    }
    if (!ul.queue('fx').length) {
        //  Handle those pesky dots
        el.find('.dot').eq(index).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        el.animate(obj, speed) && ul.animate($.extend({left: '-' + index + '00%'}, obj), speed, function(data) {
            _.i = index;

            $.isFunction(o.complete) && !callback && o.complete(el);
        });
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cqRFK/1
for the swipe event to work you need to include [jquery.event.swipe.js](https://github.com/stephband/jquery.event.swipe/blob/master/js/jquery.event.swipe.js) and change

```
if($.event.swipe) {
this.el.on('swipeleft', _.prev).on('swiperight', _.next);
}
```

on Unslider.js for

```
if($.event.special.swipe) {
this.el.on('swipeleft', _.prev).on('swiperight', _.next);
}
```

Comment: OMG! thanks.  Is it possible to instead of being slowly going back it goes back immediately but without it showing it the previous slides?

Comment: you can change speed=0 [http://jsfiddle.net/cqRFK/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/cqRFK/1/)

Comment: that speed is currnetly set to 500 which i will need but when in reverse how can i make it 0?

Comment: `if(reversespeed){
        speed=0;
    }` like the second fiddle

Comment: where in the sscript do i add this if(reversespeed){ speed=0; }?

Comment: i have updated my answer to show where to change the reverse speed if it is 0 then it will look like the slideshow go back immediately to the first li

Comment: i also had a swipe feature that was part of the script.  when using your code it wont' work.. not sure what i have to tweak to make it work with yours.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing your own from scratch though here I have made:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/agG2b/

Here is the jquery I used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide_button_left").click(function () {
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px") {
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px") {
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_2").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px") {
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_3").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px") {
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_4").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-505px"
            }, 300);

        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1010px"
            }, 300);
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px") {
            $("li.slideshow").css("margin-left")
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1515px"
            }, 300);
        }
                        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px") {
                                        $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "5px"
            }, 300, function(){
                                        $("li.slideshow1").stop().animate('margin-left', "5px");
                                        if($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "5px"){
                                                        $("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left", "-2020px")
                                                        }
                                    });
        }

    });

    $(".slide_button_right").click(function () {
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1515px"
            }, 300);
                                        if($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px"){ 
                                        $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_3").css("background", "red");
                                        }
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-2020px"
            }, 300);
                                        if($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px"){ 
                                        $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_4").css("background", "red");
                                        }
        }

        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1010px"
            }, 300);
                                        if($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px"){ 
                                        $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_2").css("background", "red");
                                        }
        }
                        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px") {
            if($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px"){ 
                                        $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
                                        $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "red");
                                        }
                                        $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-2520px"
            }, 300, function(){
                                        $("li.slideshow1").stop().animate('margin-left', "-2520px");
                                        if($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2520px"){
                                                        $("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left", "-505px")
                                                        }
                                    });
        }
    });
    $("a.slidebutton_1").click(function () {
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-505px"
            }, 300);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-505px"
            }, 380);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-505px"
            }, 460);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "red");
        }
    });
    $("a.slidebutton_2").click(function () {
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1010px"
            }, 300);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_2").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1010px"
            }, 300);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_2").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1010px"
            }, 380);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_2").css("background", "red");
        }
    });
    $("a.slidebutton_3").click(function () {
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1515px"
            }, 380);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_3").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1515px"
            }, 300);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_3").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-2020px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-1515px"
            }, 300);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_3").css("background", "red");
        }
    });
    $("a.slidebutton_4").click(function () {
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-505px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-2020px"
            }, 460);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_4").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1010px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-2020px"
            }, 380);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_4").css("background", "red");
        }
        if ($("li.slideshow1").css("margin-left") === "-1515px") {
            $("li.slideshow1").animate({
                'margin-left': "-2020px"
            }, 300);
            $("a#slide_buttons").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_1").css("background", "none");
            $("a.slidebutton_4").css("background", "red");
        }
    });
    $(".slide_button_right").mouseover(function () {
        $("a.slide_button_right").css("background-color", "#000");
        $("a.slide_button_right").css("background-size", "60px 54px");
        $("a.slide_button_right").css("background-position", "-30px 0px");
    });
    $(".slide_button_right").mouseout(function () {
        $("a.slide_button_right").css("background-color", "#fff");
        $("a.slide_button_right").css("background-size", "60px 54px");
        $("a.slide_button_right").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
    });
        $(".slide_button_left").mouseover(function () {
        $("a.slide_button_left").css("background-color", "#000");
        $("a.slide_button_left").css("background-size", "60px 54px");
        $("a.slide_button_left").css("background-position", "-30px 0px");
    });
    $(".slide_button_left").mouseout(function () {
        $("a.slide_button_left").css("background-color", "#fff");
        $("a.slide_button_left").css("background-size", "60px 54px");
        $("a.slide_button_left").css("background-position", "0px 0px");
    });
});
```

Add this:

```
<script>
if($('ul').css('left') === '300%') {
$('ul').animate({'left' : '0%'}, 5000)
}
</script>
```

To change the time it takes change the 5000 number to what you want

Comment: Thansk but i need to use what i have now.

Comment: Why do you need to use that one?